# Mapping Hierarchical Data using Spring JDBC Rowmapper

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-jdbc

I have a parent child hierarchy which I am storing in single table by maintaining self foreign key. My table columns are `ID, Name, ParentID`. Here, `ParentID` is referencing `ID` column of same table.

And my model class is like,

```
Class Model
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private Model parent;
    private List<Model> children;
}
```

How can I use `RowMapper` to map data in this model? Or, what is the best way to achieve this?

I am retrieving entire hierarchy in single query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creatre a field in your RowMapper - Map. When you parse result place each the Model items also in the map where key is the item's id.

To add a child to appropriate parent read the parent Model element from the map by parent id of curretn item.

2 things to mention

Root element has no parent.
Your query should provide correct order (parent must be processed first)

Comment: do you have corresponding code?